# No Route to Host - Android Client TCP connection

Tags: java, android, tcp

I am writing a code where the android phone is the client trying to connect to the server on my pc USING WIFI. I am opening the sockets as follows:

```
try {
  servsock = new ServerSocket(13299);
  System.out.println("Listening :13299");
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

while (true) {
  Socket sock = servsock.accept();
```

and on client side:

```
Socket sock = new Socket("192.168.0.108", 13299);
Log.i("sending","sending");
```

However I am receiving on the logcat: "No route to host" I have searched and inserted permission to use internet in the manifest.xml and did a ping from my phone with ip 192.168.0.107 to the pc server with ip 192.168.0.108.

What Am I missing? Why isn't the tcp socket connection established ? the server is written in netbeans. Does it have to do with the ports?

EDIT: I think the problem is in the IP addresses. I set the address of the server (private address) according to the output of "ipconfig" in cmd window.

Comment: Can the PC connect to itself if you telnet to 192.168.0.108 13299? May be a bind address or firewall issue.

Comment: yes i can do telnet and i turned off the firewall but still same prob

Comment: I'm guessing you tried telnet to 127.0.0.1/localhost and not 192.168.0.108 since the answer from @BrianRoach below is probably your problem.

Comment: Try specifically declaring the address of your android device by ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket( myTcpPort, 0, androidDeviceAddress ); and see what happends then, don't use wildcards.

Comment: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind                      
This is the error that i receive why i do that

Comment: @Adroidist Delete accept() and whole while loop cause it blocks connection until it's testified ( your issue lies here ), and see what happens then.

Comment: still the same. it is weird, how is a tcp connection between android device and a pc server established? is there any better way?

Comment: Did you try with a port as what was my initial suggestion? What about 8080 port ( TCP one ) If that doesn't help, post your modified code to see if something is wrong in initalization. @Adroidist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, i changed the internet access point and the app worked. My app was using a local IP to access the server.

Answer (score 0):

It must be some sort of blockage that keeps your connection to the server out of the scope for your client. Try applying different ports, and see what happens then.

Comment: i am still not able to connect, any help?